# What is a Refused Bequest?

Tags: solid-principles, duck-typing, liskov-substitution-principle

Could someone please explain what does **Refused Bequest** means?
I tried reading some articles and says its a kind of code smell or in wiki it tells that it is a class that overrides a method of a base class in such a way that the contract of the base class is not honored by the derived class.

But in a nutshell or in a more simple terms, what is it actually?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you get it. **Refused Bequest** is a code smell. But, what type of code smell? Quoting Martin Fowler's book [Refactoring: improving the design of existing code](http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html):

> Subclasses get to inherit the methods and data of their parents. But
>   what if they don't want or need what they are given? They are given
>   all these great gifts and pick just a few to play with.

You have a subclass, that inherits from a parent class, but the subclass does not need all behaviour provided by the parent class. Because of that, the subclass *refuses* some behaviour (*bequest*) of the parent class. That's why this is a code smell.

*Update answering @catzilla's comment*:

If you don't have the opportunity to read the book (I totally recommend it), at least you have the [SourceMaking page](https://sourcemaking.com/refused-bequest) that describes it pretty well.

About a code example, let's try. Let's imagine we have some classes to compute a person's taxes. We could have a class that computes government taxes:

```
class Government {
    protected double computeBaseTax() { //... }

    protected double addPersonalTax(double tax) { //... }

    public double getTax() {
        double tax = computeBaseTax();
        return addPersonalTax(tax);
    }
}
```

Then, we could have a class that computes the amount of money a company has to pay as taxes. For whatever reason, we realized this class can reuse the `addPersonalTax` method, but not `computeBaseTax()`. And taking a bad decision, we decided that our `Company` class would inherit from `Government`.

```
class Company extends Government {
    private double computeInitialTax() { //... }

    @Override 
    public double getTax() {
        double tax = computeInitialTax();
        return addPersonalTax(tax);
    }
}
```

Ok, the problem could be solved in a better way (overriding `computeBaseTax()` method) but I'm trying to ilustrate that **Refused Bequest** is a code smell that happens when we inherit from a base class and some functionality provided is refused.

Comment: If you would be so kind, can you please elaborate "refused Bequest" more.. like some simple practical code samples or some allegories that can enlighten me so that I may understand it by heart? I really want to practice best coding principles..

Comment: I've added a link where a more detailed explanation of what **Refused Bequest** is an added a code example. Hope it helps you to understand  the problem better.

Comment: your additional answer made my perception overview regarding refused bequest much clearer now.. so it means that there is unnecessary methods that is included in the inheritance and it makes the code smell.. well I think that's the simplest explanation I can understand.. well, I'm going to read your suggested links and hopefully I can learn many other things.. You deserved my vote.. :) thanks for answering!

Comment: Thanks for your vote, and I also learn while answering you. The answer is much better with your feedback and it could help to more people. Thanks.